# Hide virtual keypad in iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, datepicker, focus, keypad

I used

```
 $('input').on('focus', function() { $(this).blur(); });
```

to hide my virtual keypad appearance in iPad. But, keypad flashes once and then disappears. Is there any way I can hide it completely?

Comment: if you want the user not to be able to type anything inside the input, then why not `disable` the input?

Comment: disable how? I want him to select dates in that date picker.

Comment: you can disable an input like this `<input type="text" disabled>`